# Error in compiling process

Tags: c++, dev-c++

I have an error when I try to compile the script at http://www.exploit-db.com/exploits/16/ .
I'm using dev-c++ and it tells me this:

```
(( C:\...\Untitled1.cpp In function `void send_ping_overflow(SOCKET, DWORD, char*, short int)':
|| 104 C:\...\Untitled1.cpp name lookup of `i' changed for new ISO `for' scoping
|| 100 C:\...\Untitled1.cpp   using obsolete binding at `i'  ))
```

Comment: I don't always compile exploits but when I do I have no idea what I'm doing.

Answer (score 3):

`for (int i, ...)`

The variable `i` is being declared in the `for` loop construct. This is actually a new (relatively speaking!) ability in the C language - originally, variables needed to be declared at the top of the block in which they were used.

The incredibly obsolete compiler you're using (see [the dev-c++ tag wiki page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dev-c++)) is giving you a warning about this since you're not coding to the C99 standard or later. Note that the '99' in C99 is for 1999, or thirteen years ago. You must be writing in C90, which is from approximately twenty-one years ago.

I suggest switching to a newer/better IDE such as [Eclipse](http://eclipse.org).

Comment: +1 for "incredibly obsolete compiler you're using"

Comment: Actually it seems that OP problem is with C++, not C.

Comment: @Ivella You're right, but I enjoyed the mocking too much. The real problem is that the variable is declared in the `for` loop header and then used below the body of the loop.

Comment: The C++ standard fixed this in 1998, so it's not much of a difference.